# Updating a single row in Android ListView every millisecond from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView and ArrayAdapter set on it. My ListView single row contains TextView and start Button. When click on button the TextView text will be changed every millisecond. I have defined timer for it but when I change TextView text it doesn't appears on my view. It changes only when I call notifyDataSetChanged. But in this case calling notifyDataSetChanged every millisecond, my ListView is crashed. How can I solve this problem? In addition to I want to say that I implemented ArrayAdapter with ViewHolder pattern and overrided all necessary methods.

Comment: A Listview with just one row does seem like ...well... why use a Listview at all?

Comment: I need a ListView for it. Then I will add SeekBars for every row

Comment: Ok, so there will be more than one row. Anyway, it's difficult to help without any code. Could you show some snippets relevant to the problem?

Comment: unfortunately In this pc I don't have source code. Can you advice me how can I change listview row every millisecond?

Comment: What's the execption you're getting?

Comment: I dont get any exception but calling notifyDataSetChanged every millisecond my ListView becomes untouchable. I cant press button and so on

Comment: Put up the exception you get when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Also the code where you call this `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: public void run() {
                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timerTextView.setText(Integer.toString(totalMilliSeconds));
                        totalMilliSeconds--;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use RecyclerView it is a A flexible view for providing a limited elements into a large data set. so you can use it to control how many items should Be loaded on particular conditions. you can read about the RecyclerView [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Answer (score 2):

As Harshad wrote, you can use `RecyclerView` and it's the best way.

If for some reason you don't want, you can update specific list view row manually using this line code:

```
View convertView = listview.getChildAt(rowIndex - listview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

It's much faster than `notifyDataChanged`...

Comment: Can I do that from ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but you're updating the UI only using this line code (you can update you ArrayAdapter separately )

Answer (score 1):

I made up another solution, like RecyclerView method void notifyItemChanged(int position), create CustomBaseAdapter class just like this:

```
public abstract class CustomBaseAdapter implements ListAdapter, SpinnerAdapter {

    private final CustomDataSetObservable mDataSetObservable = new CustomDataSetObservable();

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        mDataSetObservable.registerObserver(observer);
    }

    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        mDataSetObservable.unregisterObserver(observer);
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
    }

    public void notifyItemChanged(int position) {
        mDataSetObservable.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
        mDataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated();
    }

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return getCount() == 0;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to create a CustomDataSetObservable class too for mDataSetObservable variable in CustomAdapterClass, like this:

```
public class CustomDataSetObservable extends Observable<DataSetObserver> {

    public void notifyChanged() {
        synchronized(mObservers) {
            // since onChanged() is implemented by the app, it could do anything, including
            // removing itself from {@link mObservers} - and that could cause problems if
            // an iterator is used on the ArrayList {@link mObservers}.
            // to avoid such problems, just march thru the list in the reverse order.
            for (int i = mObservers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                mObservers.get(i).onChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void notifyInvalidated() {
        synchronized (mObservers) {
            for (int i = mObservers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                mObservers.get(i).onInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }

    public void notifyItemChanged(int position) {
        synchronized(mObservers) {
            // since onChanged() is implemented by the app, it could do anything, including
            // removing itself from {@link mObservers} - and that could cause problems if
            // an iterator is used on the ArrayList {@link mObservers}.
            // to avoid such problems, just march thru the list in the reverse order.
            mObservers.get(position).onChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

on class CustomBaseAdapter there is a method notifyItemChanged(int position), and you can call that method when you want update a row wherever you want (from button click or anywhere you want call that method). And voila!, your single row will update instantly..

Hope this solution will help you..